# How to join multiples lines based on a pattern?

Tags: vim, editing

I want to join multiple lines in a file based on a pattern that both lines share.

This is my example:

```
{101}{}{Apples}
{102}{}{Eggs}
{103}{}{Beans}
{104}...
...

{1101}{}{This is a fruit.}
{1102}{}{These things are oval.}
{1103}{}{You have to roast them.}
{1104}...
...
```

I want to join the lines `{101}{}{Apples}` and `{1101}{}{This is a fruit.}`

to one line `{101}{}{Apples}{1101}{}{This is a fruit.}` for further processing.

Same goes for the other lines.

As you can see, both lines share the number 101, but I have no idea how to pull this off.
Any Ideas?

/EDIT:

I found a "workaround":

First, delete all preceding "{1" characters from group two in VISUAL BLOCK mode with `C-V` (or similar shortcut), then sort all lines by number with `:%sort n`, then join every second line with `:let @q = "Jj"` followed by `500@q`.

This works, but leaves me with `{101}{}{Apples} 101}{}{This is a fruit.}`. I would then need to add the missing characters "{1" in each line, not quite what I want. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the maximum number in each group? Are there any lines that would remain unmatched in either group?

Comment: The maximum number in each group is {219} / {1219}. No, all files would match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of deleting the `{1`, just do

```
:%sort rn /\d\d\d}/
```

That will do a numerical sort, but on each line it will only look at three digits followed by a }.

Also, to join the lines afterwards, I would do

```
:g/{\d\d\d}/j!
```

Comment: @ryz: See! I told you! @Jan: +1!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it in the shell with a file:

```
join -j 2 \
    <(sed -n '/^{...}/{s/{/{ /;s/}/ }/;p}' inputfile) \
    <(sed -n '/^{....}/{s/{./& /;s/}/ }/;p}' inputfile) |
    sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) { }{}\({[^}]*}\) {1 }\({.*}\)$/{\1}{}\2{1\1}\3/'
```

It uses the first two invocations of `sed` to split the file based on the number of digits between the first set of curly braces and adds spaces around the last three digits (`{101}` becomes `{ 101 }` and `{1101}` becomes `{1 101 }`). Then it uses those three-digit numbers as a field for the `join` command key on. The last `sed` command puts the digits back where they belong and removes the extra spaces added earlier.

A `vim` guru could probably do something better within `vim`. I could do something more straightforward than the above using AWK.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example using Vim/Ex editor from the command-line for one pattern:

```
$ ex +'redir @a|sil g/101}/' +'redi>>/dev/stdout|echon join(split(@a),"")' -scq! input.txt 
{101}{}{Apples}{1101}{}{This is a fruit.}
```

For multiple patterns, either repeat with extra commands, add a loop, or loop it from shell, e.g.

```
$ for i in `seq 1 3`; do ex +"redir @a|sil g/10$i}/" +'redi>>/dev/stdout|echo join(split(@a),"")' -scq! input.txt; done
{101}{}{Apples}{1101}{}{Thisisafruit.}
{102}{}{Eggs}{1102}{}{Thesethingsareoval.}
{103}{}{Beans}{1103}{}{Youhavetoroastthem.}
```

---

Using just shell to parse the data, it's much simpler, e.g.:

```
$ grep "101}" input.txt | xargs
{101}{}{Apples} {1101}{}{This is a fruit.}
```

For multiple lines:

```
$ for i in `seq 1 4`; do grep "10$i}" input.txt | xargs; done
{101}{}{Apples} {1101}{}{This is a fruit.}
{102}{}{Eggs} {1102}{}{These things are oval.}
{103}{}{Beans} {1103}{}{You have to roast them.}
```